# Swift 3 subscript range works for first cluster but not for middle

Tags: swift, string, subscript

I'm trying to figure out why the following works on the first string cluster (character) but not on a second one. Perhaps the endIndex cannot be applied on another String?

```
let part = "A"
let full = "ABC"

print(full[part.startIndex ... part.startIndex])                    // "A"
print(full[part.endIndex ... part.endIndex])                        // ""   <- ???
print(full[part.endIndex ... full.index(after: part.endIndex)])     // "B"
```

bSecond should hold "B", but instead is empty. But the proof that one string index works on another is that the last statement works.

EDIT:
Assuming full.hasPrefix(part) is true.

Swift puzzles.

Comment: Note that in most cases, you should never subscript a given collection with another collection's index. Although, there are some exceptions, such as with slices and collections with trivial indices, such as `Array`.

Comment: Was about to write the same :) – With `let part = ""` your code will crash.

Comment: Forgot to mention that. Assume full.hasPrefix(part)) is true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the indices of one string to subscript a different
string. That may work by chance (in your first example) or not
(in your second example), or crash at runtime.

In this particular case, `part.endIndex` (which is the "one past the end position" for the `part` string) returns

```
String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 1), _countUTF16: 0)
```

with `_countUTF16:` (which is the "count of this extended grapheme cluster in UTF-16 code units") being zero, i.e. it describes
a position (in the unicode scalar view) with no extent. Then

```
full[part.endIndex ... part.endIndex]
```

returns an empty string. But that is an implementation detail
(compare [StringCharacterView.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCharacterView.swift)). The real answer is just "you can't do that".

A safe way to obtain the intended (?) result is

```
let part = "A"
let full = "ABC"

if let range = full.range(of: part) {
    print(full[range]) // A
    if range.upperBound != full.endIndex {
        print(full[range.upperBound...range.upperBound]) // B
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin, your answer is useful, but it doesn't answer why part.endIndex works in index/after but not in subscript upper range.